# How often was this Aeon summoned?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

Near the end of Final Fantasy X it is revealed that:

> Lord Zaon was the first final Aeon forged by the bond between him and Lady Yunalesca. The old man in Zanarkand says roughly: "The final Aeon can no longer be summoned. [Zaon]'s soul is gone."
>
>  I assume, that for some time summoners could use the Aeon produced by Lord Zaons fayth to fight Sin, but no longer, which is the reason that summoners must sacrifice one of their guardians to aquire their own final Aeon.
>
>  It is also said, that this final Aeon, if it defeats Sin, becomes Sin itself. So if all of that is true, then how could a final Aeon be used multiple times? If it defeats Sin it disappears.
>  But apparently Lady Yunalesca, who was the first to defeat Sin, used a final Aeon other summoners were also able to use for some time, afterwards.

Is that poor word choice and

> Lord Zaons Aeon was also only used this one time

or is that an inconsistency in the rules?

Comment: "But apparently Lady Yunalesca, who was the first to defeat Sin, used a final Aeon other summoners were also able to use for some time, afterwards." Where did you read about that? I've never heard of this before, the only "Final" Aeon used multiple times in the games wasn't used on Sin

Comment: @CoqPwner What was it used on, then? And whether or not other summonor were able to use Yunalescas Aeon is the question. I think the quote I provided heavily implies, if not outright states it.

Comment: "*first* final Aeon" - "[This] final Aeon can no longer be summoned." - *final Aeon* is a hypernym. If this game wasn't so damn cryptic, we wouldn't be talking about it 20y later.

Comment: 'Lady Yunalesca was the first to defeat (strike: *actually destroy*) Sin *without using a final Aeon*, by just using Aeons other summoners were also able to use for some time before and afterwards.' - She broke the 'rules'.

Comment: The 'rules' were written by a nihilist who only wanted to watch the world burn and expected you to self-fulfill their prophecy. - *Ten things Yu Yevon doesn't want you to know.* - Honestly, this doesn't need any spoilers. Not because it's 20y but because nothing I just said makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

> They never say Lord Zaon was an aeon available to other summoners. He was just a Final Aeon like all the others. I will attempt to clarify the aeon process a bit so you understand.

-

> Creating an aeon requires a living person to become a fayth. The bond between summoner and fayth creates the aeon. The strength of the bond determines the strength of the aeon that is summoned.

-

> A Final Aeon follows the same process but the fayth is created from a person with a very close bond to the summoner. That bond is what makes a Final Aeon so powerful. They are called Final Aeons by the people of Spira, most of whom don't know what is really going on. From their perspective these magical Final Aeons can only be summoned one time, then they kill the summoner. Pretty final.

-

> In reality, the Final Aeon is final because after destroying Sin, Yu Yevon comes out. He uses his super summoning powers to hijack the aeon that just destroyed Sin. He uses it to kill the summoner then spends some period of time corrupting the aeon, transforming it into a new Sin that Yu Yevon can use as a host.

-

> Getting back to Lord Zaon and Lady Yunalesca, she created turned Lord Zaon into the fayth you see in Zanarkand. He would have been hijacked by Yu Yevon to create Sin, and when another summoner came along and killed that Sin, that also killed the fayth.

-

> You have hit on a bit of a plot hole, which is where are the other fayth? A thousand years of summoners coming to Zanarkand and using their guardians to create Final Aeons means Lady Yunalesca probably has a closet full of those things.

Comment: Sorry about the multiple spoiler tags, I couldn't figure out how to put them together but still have line breaks between paragraphs. If someone knows how to fix that please do or explain how.

Comment: I'm don't think that the guardian is turned into a fayth, that then creates an Aeon. As far as I understood it, Aeons are just another form of the fayth. For example Bahamut having a small child form, when it is a "fayth", but when being summoned being a dragon thing. Otherwise Jekkt would not be Sin, only the Aeon he created, would be.

Comment: @Minix No, it's a separate thing. The aeons never talk directly, only their fayth form does. And with Jecht, we see him and talk to him as a person, but then the creature we fight that looks like him is called Braska's Final Aeon, not Jecht. Sin is the fayth and the aeon, Yu Yevon absorbs them both. Don't ask how it works though, they leave a lot of those details vague in the story.

Comment: So what you are saying is then, that the citation I've given in the question is just worded poorly, and that Lord Zaon was only summoned once and consequently died/was transformed, meaning his soul was gone immediately?

Comment: @Minix - "I assume, that for some time summoners could use the Aeon produced..." [citation not to be found]. "Lord Zaon was only summoned once" : correct.

Comment: "most of whom don't know what is really going on" - yeah, they're going to have to get in line.... +1 (use #Spoiler! as a header and no spoilers. Nobody knows wtf is going on here anyway.

Comment: @Mazura It's been 4 months and you're the only one complaining. I think we're fine here.

Comment: It also took you 4 months to get an upvote.... You did ask "how to fix that".

Comment: @Mazura This answer was posted yesterday. If you don't have anything of substance to contribute, please refrain from making (multiple) comments.